# TagManger classes vanished in PlayServices 8.1.0?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-tag-manager

I get multiple errors since I upgraded to the PlayServices 8.1.0. Where the tag manager classes moved to another/new dependency?

I find no references for this error:

```
Error:(27, 40) Gradle: error: package com.google.android.gms.tagmanager does not exist
Error:(90, 12) Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class TagManager
Error:(456, 41) Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class ContainerHolder
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dependencies{
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
}
```

with above dependency I still able to get `TagManager` class.